# Single file versioning best practices?

Tags: objective-c

User is selecting rather hefty single XML files via an NSOpenPanel. The application is making moderate changes to the file so I'd like to include an option of creating a backup in a subfolder based on the directory the original file was selected. Creating the new subfolder is no problem but does anybody have a good way to to create a backup of said foo.xml, is there a practice for such thing or is it as simple as creating a duplicate and renaming it foo.back01.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, how much this Approach will fit with your requirement, but this is what i was doing,

-- Have a directory in the Temporary folder of the System : Assuming once the Application is closed all this files will be deleted,

-- To have the uniqueness in the file, generate file name with following pattern , have a function say [+(NSString *) generateFileNameForExtension:(NSString *)extension Create:(bool)bCreate]

Assuming input is .xml and false , it might give fileName something like this,

AppName128908765445.xml , i.e. [AppName][UTCTimeStamp].[Fileextension]

-- Once you think its done, there could be Function call [self addToDeleteList:(NSString *)fileName] which will add a file to delete list,

-- There would be a function, which shall invoke a timer for 1 minute and every one minute it will read all the files gets added into delete list then delete it.

Will share the code with you if needed...